# Is there a way to override a plugin to show in source instead of just wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to implement most of CKEditor plugins in source only mode. Unfortunately I can't find ways to switch the modes property of the plugin to source mode as well.

One of the plugin that I'd like to allow in source is the text color picker. 
Here's the source code of the CKEditor color picker;

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/dc8dccc5eb8c22b69a1061ea130cf090da4e3ebf/plugins/colorbutton/plugin.js

Notice the modes attribute is set to `modes: {wysiwyg:1}`. I'd like to add `source:1` into it so it would enable, but how?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to work at all. This plugin was implemented to work in WYSIWYG mode and it's impossible to enable it in source mode. These are two completely different environments.

Comment: I thought of overriding the methods, but it seems like each core plugin is created differently from another and isn't consistent throughout the board..